# c# Не получается вытащить названия папок с Directory.GetDirectories(path)

Tags: c#

Требуется вытащить только названия папок. Делать рекурсию, возвращать вложенные папки, имена файлов и пути - не нужно.

```
        private static List<string> AllFolders(string FolderPath)
    {
        List<string> folders = new List<string>();
        foreach (var d in Directory.GetDirectories(FolderPath))
        {
            var dir = new DirectoryInfo(d);
            var dirName = dir.Name;
            folders.Add(dirName);
            Console.WriteLine(folders); 
        }
        Console.WriteLine("folders: ", folders);
        return folders;
    }
```

Несложная задача, но если надо получить вывод в консоль. Если требуется `return` то работающих примеров я не видел.

В цикле в консоль выводится то что нужно, при дебаге это тоже видно - `folders` наполняется. Но итоговый список будет пустым либо вернёт

```
`Directory.GetDirectories System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]`
```

Если вынести список на верхний уровень - результат тот же.

Эту задачу (список через `return`) вообще можно решить?

И если нет, то как можно ли получить одним списком все папки заданной директории?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Directory.GetDirectories(path)` уже вам возвращает массив который достаточно превратить в список с помощью `ToList()`

К слову, дебажить в консоли так себе идея. Вы можете делать [точки остановки](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8+%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0+visual+studio&rlz=1C1GCEU_ruRU968RU968&oq=%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8+%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8+vi&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0i22i30.5681j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) и смотреть значения переменных

```
private static List<string> GetDirectories(string directory)
{
    return Directory.GetDirectories(directory).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Преобразуете `string[]` в список то зачем? Лишняя работа, возвращайте массив. Либо используйте `EnumerateDirectories` вместо `GetDirectories`, так хоть выделение памяти под массив не потребуется.

Comment: @aepot попросили список - будет список. А вот на счет EnumerateDirectories не совсем понял, разве EnumerableDirectories не будет возвращать список какой-то? Он тоже память будет занимать

Comment: IEnumerable<T>, паттерн итератор, итерироваться можно не только по живой коллекции. Никаких списков или массивов там нет.